# defining a folder location in order to recall it

Tags: theme-development, php

I'm creating a child theme off of wp-framework and in it's header it uses

```
<?php echo IMAGES . '/favicon.ico'; ?>
```

to recall the folder where images are kept.

How do I define or create the location in order to recall it using echo IMAGES?

and if I can save the image folder location as IMAGES (If I recall it's a string?) can I do the same with other information?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here - do you want an image subfolder in your child theme? If so, you can use bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') to get the path to your child theme and then just append /images to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many WordPress frameworks include helper functions and pre-defined folder locations.  WP Framework is very well coded but requires some learning and inspecting the code to find the documentation.

In the file core.php many constants are defined but I did not see IMAGES but THEME_IMAGE is defined so it is likely that IMAMGE refers to the images folder in the child theme directory.

Here is the list of constants available for you to use:

WP Framework V 3.6 core.php:

```
function wpf_initial_constants() {  
    // Sets the File path to the current parent theme's directory.
    define( 'PARENT_THEME_DIR', TEMPLATEPATH );

    // Sets the URI path to the current parent theme's directory.
    define( 'PARENT_THEME_URI', get_template_directory_uri() );

    // Sets the File path to the current parent theme's directory.
    define( 'CHILD_THEME_DIR', STYLESHEETPATH );

    // Sets the URI path to the current child theme's directory.
    define( 'CHILD_THEME_URI', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );

    // Sets the file path to WP Framework
    define( 'WPF_DIR', PARENT_THEME_DIR . '/framework' );

    // Sets the URI path to WP Framework
    define( 'WPF_URI', PARENT_THEME_URI . '/framework' );

    // Sets the file path to extensions
    define( 'WPF_EXT_DIR', WPF_DIR . '/extensions' );

    // Sets the URI path to extensions
    define( 'WPF_EXT_URI', WPF_URI . '/extensions' );
}

/**
 * Templating constants that you can override before WP Framework is loaded.
 *
 * @since 0.3.0
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wpf_templating_constants() {
    // Sets a unique ID for the theme.
    if ( !defined( 'THEME_ID' ) )
        define( 'THEME_ID', 'wpf_' . get_template() );

    // Sets the default theme options db name
    if ( !defined( 'THEME_OPTIONS' ) )
        define( 'THEME_OPTIONS', 'theme_options' );

    // Sets relative paths for the default directories/paths
    if ( !defined( 'THEME_LIBRARY' ) )
        define( 'THEME_LIBRARY', '/library' );

    if ( !defined( 'THEME_I18N' ) )
        define( 'THEME_I18N', THEME_LIBRARY . '/languages' );

    if ( !defined( 'THEME_FUNC' ) )
        define( 'THEME_FUNC', THEME_LIBRARY . '/functions' );

    if ( !defined( 'THEME_IMG' ) )
        define( 'THEME_IMG', THEME_LIBRARY . '/images' );

    if ( !defined( 'THEME_CSS' ) )
        define( 'THEME_CSS', THEME_LIBRARY . '/css' );

    if ( !defined( 'THEME_JS' ) )
        define( 'THEME_JS', THEME_LIBRARY . '/js' );

    // Sets the default custom header image
    if ( !defined( 'DEFAULT_HEADER_IMAGE' ) )
        define( 'DEFAULT_HEADER_IMAGE', get_theme_part( THEME_IMG . '/custom-header.gif' ) );
}
```

Comment: thanks Chris, I think the other answer is the one I was after. I wasn't able to properly articulate what I was trying to do - however what you have showed me has saved me hours of work now that I know that these constants exist :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to define/redefine a constant:

```
define( 'IMAGES', 'path/to/images/directory' );
```

If you need to echo `parent-theme\images`:

```
<?php echo get_template_direcory_uri() . '/images'; ?>
```

If you need to echo `child-theme\images`:

```
<?php echo get_stylesheet_direcory_uri() . '/images'; ?>
```

Or do you need to do something else?

Comment: I think the top one - I need to define a constant (sorry I'm self taught & don't know all the jargon yet) such as the location of the images folder, or the folder where some static html files will reside that kind of thing.